# c# tasks async/await or ContinueWith or?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I call 2 same tasks from main (like this

```
static void Main()
    {
        Downloads test = new Downloads();
        test.DisplayResultAsync();
        test.DisplayResultAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("main");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

), where `DisplayResultAsync` is

```
        public async Task DisplayResultAsync()
        {

            byte[] result = await DownLoadFile();
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading complete", result[0]);
        }

        static  Task<byte[]> DownLoadFile()
        {
            FileDownLoader flDl = new FileDownLoader();

            return  Task.Run(() =>
            {
                byte[] result = flDl.Download("test"); 
               return result;
            });
        }
```

I want execute this task in background, but the second task should begin when the first is finished.

FileDownLoader code:

```
class FileDownLoader
    {
        public byte[] Download(string url)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        }
    }
```

what should I use? because this task executing together

Comment: Did you try awaiting? Seems kind of silly to ask us when you can try yourself.

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep, use Task.Delay, even for testing, its going to behave differently. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues here. First, you'll want to use [asynchronous file I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys) to perform the actual file downloads so you're not blocking threads. It appears your `FileDownLoader` class is just faking it for now, and that's fine but let's at least fake it asynchronously:

```
class FileDownLoader
{
    public async byte[] DownloadAsync(string url)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```

What that allows you to do is get rid of `Task.Run` in your calling code. (With I/O-bound work like this, async is all about consuming fewer threads, not more. Anytime you see `Task.Run` in an async method, it's *usually* a sign you've done something wrong.)

Moving on, you can combine `DisplayResultAsync` and `DownLoadFile` into just this:

```
public async Task DownloadAndDisplayResultAsync()
{
    FileDownLoader flDl = new FileDownLoader();
    byte[] result = await flDl.DownloadAsync("test");
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading complete", result[0]);
}
```

You want to call the above method twice, but you don't want the second call to start until the first completes. `await` allows you to do this very easily and without blocking, but you can only do it from an `async` method (not `Main`), so let's introduce a new method in your console app:

```
static async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    Downloads test = new Downloads();
    await test.DisplayResultAsync();
    await test.DisplayResultAsync();
}
```

Now we just need to call it from `Main`. You said you want the downloads to happen "in the background", so presumably you have some "foreground" work that you want to do concurrently. That goes where commented:

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = DoWorkAsync();
    // do "foreground" work here
    task.Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As a side note, another rule of thumb with async code is that you should never block an async call with `.Wait()` or `.Result`, *except* in the `Main` method of a console app. Use `await` in all other situations.